# Is there any way to clean up the following generic method using any of the new C# 4 features?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0

I've just modified a method for handling my DDD commands (previously it had no return type):

```
public static CommandResult<TReturn> Execute<TCommand, TReturn>(TCommand command) 
     where TCommand : IDomainCommand
{
    var handler = IoCFactory.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand, TReturn>>();
    return handler.Handle(command);
}
```

The method is fine, and does what I want it to do, however using it creates some fugly code:

```
CommandResult<Customer> result = 
    DomainCommands.Execute<CustomerCreateCommand, Customer>
    (
        new CustomerCreateCommand(message)
    );
```

Before I added the `Customer` return type `TReturn`, it was nice and tidy and the method could infer the types from its usage. However that's no longer possible.

Is there any way using any new C# features that I could rewrite the above to make it tidier, i.e. using Func, Action, Expression, etc? I'm probably expecting the impossible, but I'm getting fed up of writing so much code to just call a single method that used to be very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to reduce it slightly is to have a static generic type for the type parameter that *can't* be inferred, allowing you to have a generic method with just one type parameter that *can* be inferred:

```
public static class DomainCommands<TReturn>
{
    public static CommandResult<TReturn> Execute<TCommand>(TCommand command) 
        where TCommand : IDomainCommand
   {
      var handler = IoCFactory.GetInstance<ICommandHandler<TCommand, TReturn>>();
      return handler.Handle(command);
   }
}
```

Then:

```
var result = DomainCommands<Customer>.Execute(new CustomerCreateCommand(msg));
```

It's not *much* nicer, but it's slightly better. Of course, if the domain command type itself could be generic, that might help - so `CustomerCreateCommand` would implement `IDomainCommand<Customer>` for example. If you still needed a nongeneric IDomainCommand, you could make `IDomainCommand<T>` derive from `IDomainCommand`.